# Google analytics duration zero for the pages visited by Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-analytics

I want to visit a web site with Selenium and python like this:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(20)
browser.close()
```

When I check the duration in google analytic after an hour, I see the duratioin is zero.
I've change it to this code to click on a link in the page after 30 seconds:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(30)
elm = browser.find_element_by_xpath(link)
elm.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(10)
browser.quit()
```

But nothing has changes.
what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Session duration is the delta between the timestamps of the first and the last interaction within a session (i.e. interactions with the same client id within a given timeframe). As far as I can tell your code will only create a single interaction per session, so there is no second data point to calculate a duration.

Comment: I've updated the question with news code. I click on a link after 30 seconds. but the same result. what to do now?